# WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 integration with WSO2 APIM Analytics 2.6.0 ( Stream Processor 4.3.0)

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am working with WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 version and trying to integrate with WSO2 APIM Analytics Server as per the link [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#MSSQL-AM_USAGE_UPLOADED_FILES]

Already, we have working application of WSO2 APIM 2.5.0 and Analytics ti it and the data is generated as it should be. However, due to technical road block in APIM 2.5.0 ( adding certificate using RestAPIs), I am trying to migrate APIM from 2.5.0 to 2.6.0.

APIM is migrated as it is provided in the documentation link [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#code]
 but when I am trying to integrate with Analytics, It throws constant error like below

```
[2019-09-09 10:03:17,367]  INFO 
{org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected
[2019-09-09 10:03:17,368] ERROR 
{org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} - Dropping 
wrongly formatted event sent 
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error 
when converting loganalyzer:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
    at 
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:188)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 present in cache
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:171)
        ... 7 more

[2019-09-09 10:14:02,374]  INFO {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.mgwfile.task.MGWFileCleanUpTask} - Uploaded API Usage data in the db will be cleaned up to : 2019-09-04 10:14:02.374
[2019-09-09 10:18:17,343] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} - Dropping wrongly formatted event sent org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting loganalyzer:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:188)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 present in cache
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:171)
        ... 7 more
```

Can some one please let me know if the compatibility exists between APIM 2.6.0 and Analytics as while migration process, I read while migrating the Analytics part of APIM - in Note Section [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#code]

Step 3.1 - Note that it is mandatory to use a WUM updated WSO2 API Manager Analytics 2.6.0 pack when migrating the configurations for WSO2 API-M Analytics.

Can some one please let me know why this constant errors are thrown at Analytics server. I have started the worker node of stream processor and as I understand there should be one carbon app which can receive the LogAnalyzer Events from APIM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Log analyser analytics is depreciated in APIM analytics 2.6.0. Remove the log analyser publisher from APIM 2.6.0

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will remove it and will check.